# What is the proper way of handling xml-stylesheet :xmlns:blah with haml?

Tags: rss, haml, atom-feed, merb

I'm trying to hook up a blog with some xml namespaces and xml stylesheets.

The ugly way that I'm doing this currently looks like so:

```
!!! XML
= partial('xmlstyle')
%channel
......blah.....
= partial('xmlend')
```

where

_xmlstyle.xml.erb looks like:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" media="screen" href="/~d/styles/rss2full.xsl"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" media="screen" 
href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~d/styles/itemcontent.css"?>
<rss xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" 
xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" 
xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" 
xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" 
xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0" version="2.0">
```

_xmlend.xml.erb looks like:

```
</rss>
```

Should I just stick with erb for now?
There has to be a way of doing this in haml right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haml doesn't have syntax for XML stylesheet directives, but there's no reason you can't include them directly. As for the `xmlns:blah` attributes, you can either use strings as the attribute names, like so:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" media="screen" href="/~d/styles/rss2full.xsl"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~d/styles/itemcontent.css"?>
%rss{"xmlns:content" => "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/",
     "xmlns:wfw" => "http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/",
     "xmlns:dc" => "http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/",
     "xmlns:atom" => "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom",
     "xmlns:sy" => "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/",
     "xmlns:slash" => "http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/",
     "xmlns:feedburner" => "http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0",
     :version => "2.0"}
  %channel
    blah
```

You could also use HTML-style attributes with `()`:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" media="screen" href="/~d/styles/rss2full.xsl"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" media="screen" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~d/styles/itemcontent.css"?>
%rss(xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
     xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
     xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
     xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
     xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
     xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
     xmlns:feedburner="http://rssnamespace.org/feedburner/ext/1.0"
     version="2.0")
  %channel
    blah
```

Comment: Awesome. The `%rss{ "xmlns:atom" => "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" }`bit was exactly what I was looking for.